# How can I detect a user login programmatically?

Tags: users, login, inotify

I am developing a small daemon program which needs to run some instructions when a user logs onto the system (all kinds of logins included). In order to do so, I want my program to be woken up whenever this login event occurs. However, I don't want it to check periodically whether a new user arrived, which means it must not:

- Read log files such as `/var/log/auth.log` periodically. Besides the fact that I would have to actually parse the file, I would also probably do it far too often (since there are very few logins on my system).
- Check the output of another command such as `ps`, `who` or `w` and keep track of users internally. Using this method, the program could *miss* some logins, in case someone logs in and out before my program runs its checks on the output.

Since I don't want my program to waste time, I thought about using I/O events, however... I don't quite see where to *hook*. I have tried watching over `/var/run/utmp` (using `inotify`) but it doesn't seem to react correctly: my program receives a lot of events when terminals are opened/closed, but very few when someone actually logs in (if any at all). Additionally, these events are hardly recognisable, and change from a login attempt to another. For the record, here is a little set of what I was able to *catch* when running `su user`:

- When a terminal opens: `IN_OPEN` (file was opened), `IN_CLOSE_NOWRITE` (unwrittable file closed), sometimes `IN_ACCESS` (file was accessed, when using `su -l`).
- When `su` is started (password prompt): a few events with no identifier (`event.mask = 0`).
- After a successful login attempt (shell started as another user) : nothing.
- When closing the terminal: another set of unnamed events.

Is there another way to hook a program onto "*user logins*"? Is there a file reflecting user logins on which I could use an `inotify` watch (just like I could use one on `/proc` to detect process creations) ? I had another look at `/proc` contents but nothing seems to be quite what I need.

<sub>*Side note* : I thought about posting this on Stack Overflow since it is programming-related, but beyond implementation, I am more interested by the "visible" reactions a Linux system has when a user logs in (by "visible", I mean reactions we could observe/detect/watch out for, programmatically, without wasting time).</sub>

Comment: Based on your mention of `/var/log/auth.log`, we can assume you're not using the journal from systemd, right?

Comment: @CristianCiupitu I gave this file as an example as it is related to logins, but I didn't even bother trying to use it since reading a log file regularly is not quite what I am trying to do, whether it is this one, or another resource provided by `systemd`.

Comment: Would monitoring [/var/log/wtmp](http://linux.die.net/man/5/wtmp) do what you want? Unlike utmp, it only grows (except when logrotate truncates it).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Does your system use Pluggable Authentication Modules (PAM)? Most modern [Linux](http://www.linux-pam.org/) or [BSD](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/articles/pam/) use PAM.

PAM allows you to hook into logins. There are a variety of PAM modules available which might meet your needs, or you can write your own in C. There is even a [pam-python](http://pam-python.sourceforge.net/)<sup>*</sup> binding which allows you to hook in Python code.

Given that you want the daemon to be running continuously, I would opt for a simple PAM module which logs to a file and signals the daemon.

<sub><sup>*</sup>The package is named `libpam-python` under Debian and Ubuntu.</sub>

Comment: Actually, I already developed a few PAM modules myself, and I thought about it after posting my question. However, I need a program which runs continuously (so, a daemon), while reacting to logins (without interfering with the auth. process itself). I could develop a PAM module to communicate with this daemon when someone logs in, but that would require me to develop both the module and the daemon. I will go for this solution and accept this answer unless someone gives me a way to hook on logins directly from the daemon.

Comment: @JohnWHSmith A PAM module is exactly the right way to solve this problem. It may certainly involve notifying a daemon.

Comment: @Gilles Let's go for this then, I'll develop a little module and connect the pieces with a pipe or a UNIX socket. I'll have a quick look at `wtmp` on my way there though. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It might be possible for a sufficiently crafty/devious user to defeat this, but you should be able to catch most logins if you put a command into `/etc/profile` to notify your daemon.  It could be something simple, like running `who am i` with output redirected to a fifo that your daemon would read.